# hs-minor-mode with python.el - hide if statements, for/while loops, etc

Tags: python, code-folding

Currently, I use the `hs-minor-mode` to collapse my python code and make it easier to work with - however, by default this only folds `def my_function():` blocks. Is it possible to get it to work with `if`, `for`, `while` etc. blocks as well?

If not, does anyone know a better option for code folding? I do use `C-s` and `M-x occur` to move around my code already, I just sometimes like to fold my code so I don't have so much to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little more looking around, I found:

- [Origami](https://github.com/gregsexton/origami.el)
- [yafolding](https://github.com/zenozeng/yafolding.el)

Which can do what I wanted (and possibly a little more). I haven't thoroughly tested them both out, but on first impression, yafolding is working the best so far on python.el.

Answer (score 0):

I use spacemacs distro and was struggling with this issue. Use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dsjt/24fa4e68637f7927b1b720f505109aec) to get `hideshow` folding to work with indentation.

Edit:
Sure Drew, here's the elaboration.

1. Add both the snippets found in the link to `user-init()` function of .spacemacs file
2. Call `hs-hide-level` using `M-x` or keybind it, the way shown below

```lisp
  (with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
    (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "zs") 'hs-hide-level))
```

right after the pasted snippets

3. Profit :)

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, so it risks being deleted. Please summarize the answer that you invite readers to find at that link destination. Thx.